# How to find min value in triple RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to find minimum value over RDD triples. This is how I approach this task (saving to file is done for validation).

```
evalsRDD.coalesce(1)
            .map(e => "%.3f\t%d\t%.3f".format(e._1, e._2, e._3))
            .saveAsTextFile("data/streaming/test")

val minRMSE = evalsRDD.min()(new Ordering[(Any, Any, Double)]() {
  override def compare(x: (Any, Any, Double), y: (Any, Any, Double)): Double =
    Ordering[Double].compare(x._3, y._3) })
```

It says that method compare has incompatible type. How to solve this issue?

Comment: what type is `evalsRDD`?

Comment: @Tzach Zohar: It's of the type `RDD[(Any, Any, Double)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `compare` method must return an `Int`, not a `Double`, to override the method defined in `Ordering`.

If you change it do to so, it works:

```
val minRMSE = evalsRDD.min()(new Ordering[(Any, Any, Double)]() {
  override def compare(x: (Any, Any, Double), y: (Any, Any, Double)): Int =
    Ordering[Double].compare(x._3, y._3) 
})
```